# GORM skips ids when fails to create account in Postgres

Tags: go, go-gorm

My code:

```
func (s *service) CreateAccount(account *models.Account) error {
    result := s.db.Create(account)

    if result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully created!")

    return nil
}
```

Yes, that works well. But in case when I create an account with the same email I get:

```
"ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uni_accounts_email\" (SQLSTATE 23505)"
```

Account type:

```
type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email       string    `json:"email" gorm:"unique"`
    Password    string    `json:"-"`
    FirstName   string    `json:"firstName"`
    LastName    string    `json:"lastName"`
    Birthday    time.Time `json:"birthday"`
    PhoneNumber string    `json:"phoneNumber"`
    Cards       []Card    `gorm:"foreignKey:AccountID" json:"cards,omitempty"`
}
```

The problem is when the fail happens the id moves by 1 (increments).

Example:
If user created with id = 5 successfully, and then fails 2 times. Then, next data row created will have id = 8.

So, how can I fix that movement such that id will not move?

Comment: Yes, this is how sequences work. You can also get gaps if doing operations concurrently. Why is it a problem?

Comment: So @erikkallen, you mean it is fine that it moves, right?

Comment: The guarantee you get is that every value is unique. Not that every value exists

Comment: Aside from the little fact that the ID is totally not the problem here. The problem is that evidently multiple accounts with the same email are created. So in fact, the same account is written multiple times, where it should be written only once. In other words: if your condition for account creation fails, the account data should not be written to the database.